# Proving the inverse of an adjugate matrix exists

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the following expression $$A^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\det(A)} \text{adj}(A)$$

Since the inverse of $A$ obviously must exist for this to hold, we know that $A$ is invertible. We can rewrite the expression as $\text{adj}^{-1} (A) = \dfrac{1}{\det(A)}A.$

My question is as follows - since we know $A$ exists and $\dfrac{1}{\det{(A)}}$ also exists and is defined (i.e. not zero), is this enough to prove that $\text{adj}^{-1} (A)$ must exist?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then, yes, the adjugate is also invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

The fundamental relation which proves your assertion is this:
$$\operatorname{adj}A\cdot A=A\cdot\operatorname{adj}A=(\det A) I$$
where $I$ is the unit matrix of dimension $\dim A$.